# Pandas giving file not found error while trying to access csv via anaconda prompt

Tags: python, pandas

Beginner here. trying to load this table via python so i can figure out how i can manipulate it and gain some insight with the eventual intention of calculating the WOE and/or running a regression.

The command ran fine on a test db of two rows i created so it must be something to do with the format of the csv im trying to use. Its a file with 8000 customers and 50 associated variables including some dates and then counts, sums and averages for 30, 60 and 90 day windows of a number of different factors. Could any of this be the reason i get the error message at the bottom?

(* are just redaction's)

```
 data = pd.read_csv("C:\Users\******\Desktop\*******.csv")

>>> data = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\******\Desktop\**************")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\******\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 702, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Users\******\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 429, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\******\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 895, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "C:\Users\******\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1122, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
  File "C:\Users\******\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1853, in __init__
    self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 387, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 705, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'C:\\Users\\******\\Desktop\\**************' does not exist: b'C:\\Users\\******\\Desktop\\**************'
```

....

Answer (score 0):

You should replace single backslash with double backslash, like so

```
data = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users******\\Desktop*******.csv")
```

or prefix path with r

```
data = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users******\Desktop*******.csv")
```

See [here](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html) for full description on which characters need escaping in python strings.

Comment: Or just add `r` in front of path `pd.read_csv(r"C:\User...")`

Comment: SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(hi)?
>>> data = pd.read_csv(r"C:\\Users\\*******\\Desktop\\*******")
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 705, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'C:\\\\Users\\\\*******\\\\Desktop\\\\*******' does not exist: b'C:\\\\Users\\\\*******\\\\Desktop\\\\*******'
>>>

Comment: Its returned a similar error again just with more backslashes

Comment: Either add r or double backslash, do not do both!

Comment: >>> data = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\*******\\Desktop\\*******.csv")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 705, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'C:\\Users\\*******\\Desktop\\*******.csv' does not exist: b'C:\\Users\\*******\\Desktop\\*******.csv'

Comment: Still getting the same error for both though. must be the data in the file right? I got the location string from the files properties so that cant be wrong

Comment: it looks like you missed final backslash

Answer (score 0):

add r(raw string) before ":

```
data = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users******\Desktop*******.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

Its better to create a separate folder where keep both data and your csv file...

Then just read by only file name... Try to press tab when you are in parenthesis
 because it will give you also suggestion where you will see if the file is available or not.

```
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv)
```

Comment: >>> pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Joe.Welford\\Desktop\\PythonData\\HiBye.csv")
   Hi  Bye
0   1    2
>>> pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Joe.Welford\\Desktop\\PythonData\\*************.csv"
...

Comment: Put my test table and my main one into a new folder as you suggest and it worked for the top one. Do the ...'s mean that it is processing the file? It is a fairly large file of around 4 mill cells (8000 x 500)

Comment: I suppose since i only did PD.read.... rather than affixing a suffix to it it is attempting to display the output within this console? Which might be too much for it?]#

Comment: Ah never mind ... means are you gonna close the script aka no bracket